# Rails 4 + Devise - User.find_by problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

This code:

```
def getUser(email_address)
    User.find_by :email email_address
end
```

throws a syntax error:

```
requests_controller.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
```

where this code (implemented in the exact same place/function without changing anything else) works:

```
def getUser(email_address)
    users = User.all
    found_user = nil
    users.each  do |user|
        if user.email == email_address
            found_user = user
            break
        end
    end
    found_user
end
```

Clearly the second implementation is horrible.  With larger numbers of users its going to slow and stop.  But I cannot see why the first one - which should be the right way to do it - will not even compile.

The syntax error message occurs when the class is loaded, before even the method is called.  There is no issue with unbalanced "if" / "end" because the only lines changed are the ones shown.

I cannot understand why.  I have tried lots of variations on this but none of them work.

As far as I can tell there should be no need to post more of my code, but if really someone wants me to I will.  Note that this is not inside a devise controller, its just one of my other app controllers.  But, User.all works, so why does User.find_by not even compile?

This [page from the ActiveRecord docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database) suggests it should work.  Loads of [tutorials and help pages such as this one](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-finding_user_objects) suggests that exact syntax.  Devise must be doing something very surprising to the ActiveRecord api to break things this comprehensively.

Anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
User.where(email: email_address).first
```

About the error: there is no comma between arguments.

Comment: Looks good.  Thanks for this.  I haven't tried this as I managed to get find_by to work as below.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a large typo when copying the syntax from the guides - you've turned a hash (eg. `email: email_address`) into a symbol and a string (`:email email_address`). Note the positioning of the colon.

It sounds like you are unfamiliar with Ruby 1.9 hash syntax - typing `email: email_address` is a shortcut for typing `:email => email_address`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this

```
def getUser(email_address)
    User.find_by(:email => email_address)
end
```

To find this I grepped through /var/lib/gems looking for examples of find_by, and saw this:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.2/test/rails_app/app/mongoid/shim.rb

def find_by_email(email)
   find_by(:email => email)
end
```

How the [example from the ActiveRecord docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database) is supposed to work I don't know, because I could not even get it to compile.  :-(

Comment: thats the exact same syntax as in the guides. Section 1.1.5 - `Client.find_by first_name: 'Lifo'`

Answer (score 0):

@Sez, you are missing something that everyone else here is missing - it's because your syntax is WRONG. No one else caught it, you are not passing a hash you are passing to separate statements. You are mixing two types of hash syntax and not getting a hash.

`User.find_by :email => email_address` # or

`User.find_by email: email_address` # Yours:

`User.find_by :email email_address # Subtle mistake, the error message also sucks`

:email is a symbol, email: is syntax for a symbol IN a hash.

:-) Happy fun for everyone looking at this!